# Vue v-select array of objects

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to bind an array of objects to a v-select so that when the user selects an option, I have access to multiple data points associated with that option. However, I only want it to show one value in the dropdown itself, which would be the name. If I use itemText to have it displayed correctly in the dropdown, it binds it to that name only and I do not have access to the rest of the info associated with it.

For example, here is my array of objects:

```
    memberships = [{
     memberExpirationDate: (...),
     memberUsername: 'John Jones',
     membershipId: 234
     membershipProfileName: 'Sample Profile Name'
    }]
```

And here is my v-select:

```
    <v-select v-model="selectedMember"
       :items="memberships"
       item-text="membershipProfileName"
       filled
       required>
    </v-select>
```

Then when I want to use `selectedMember` it is set to 'Sample Profile Name' instead of the entire membership object. How would I bind the value to the entire object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the `return-object` prop on your `v-select` seems to be the simplest way to return the entire object, instead of just the selected member's name.

Simply add the `return-object` prop, and the entire object will be returned each time instead, like so:

```html
<v-select 
    v-model="selectedMember" 
    :items="memberships" 
    item-text="memberUsername"
    filled 
    return-object  ADD IT HERE
></v-select>
```

Here's a demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    selectedMember: {
      memberExpirationDate: '2/3/21',
      memberUsername: 'John Jones',
      membershipId: 234,
      membershipProfileName: 'Sample Profile Name'
    },
    memberships: [{
      memberExpirationDate: '2/3/21',
      memberUsername: 'John Jones',
      membershipId: 234,
      membershipProfileName: 'Sample Profile Name'
    }, {
      memberExpirationDate: '2/4/21',
      memberUsername: 'John Jones II',
      membershipId: 235,
      membershipProfileName: 'Sample Profile Name II'
    }, {
      memberExpirationDate: '2/5/21',
      memberUsername: 'John Jones III',
      membershipId: 236,
      membershipProfileName: 'Sample Profile Name III'
    }]
  },
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div id="app">
  <v-app style="padding: 30px;">

    <v-select v-model="selectedMember" :items="memberships" item-text="memberUsername" return-object filled></v-select>

    <pre>{{ selectedMember }}</pre>
  </v-app>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Linx - Hopefully this answered your question, but please let me know if you have any other ones related to this, or if there's something here you need explained in more detail.

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much

Comment: Sure thing, glad to help!